# exerr:ERROR err:XPST0003: EOF or zero-length string found where a valid XPath expression was expected

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I'm a beginner at XQuery. I'm trying to write a function for a project, but I get this error message:

> exerr:ERROR err:XPST0003: EOF or zero-length string found where a valid XPath expression was expected.

This is my XQuery:

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare function local:trovaMatricola($str as xs:string?){
 let $liv := doc("/db/apps/prova/data/utenti.xml")/utenti/utente[matricola=$str]/livello
 let $val := local:valore($liv)
 return $val
};

declare function local:valore($liv as xs:string?){
 let $val := doc("/db/apps/prova/data/fiaba.xml")/text/$liv
 return $val
};
```

Comment: A few general hints on asking questions: if you reference data in your question, make sure it is available, preferably as a small (but well-formed for XML contents) extract if it is large. Make sure to add the _expected output_ of your query. English variable and function names would help us at understanding what's going on (and if the data is in another language, think about whether it might be reasonable to provide a short "dictionary" of what the values means). Not all of this is really needed for this question, but keep it in mind for questions in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not writing XQuery modules, you need to supply an actual query. As is, you only declared the XQuery version and two functions, but there is nothing to be actually executed.

This also explains the error message:

> exerr:ERROR err:XPST0003: EOF or zero-length string found where a valid XPath expression was expected.

The XQuery engine parsed the functions, but is still looking for a statement to execute. The restriction to "XPath expressions" seems a little bit misleading.

Comment: so how can i write an XQuery module? i'm trying to query first an xml document to take a value and use it to make another query on another xml file.. 
Example:
i put in input this value: 1111
the program should make a query on this file: 
<users>
<user>
<code>1111</code>
<level>s</level>
</user>
</users>

give me the value of the tag <level> and use this value to make a query on another file:

<text>
<s>once upon a time....</s>
</text>

and my output should be 

"once upon a time.."

Comment: The [BaseX documentation has an example](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Repository#Accessing_Modules) that might already be sufficient to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

@JensErat has given you the answer, but to add to it, here's a tip: there are quite a few XQuery engines about, and if you are mystified by an error message from one of them, it may be a good idea to see what a different XQuery engine tells you. None of them will ever get all diagnostics perfectly right, but here is what Saxon tells you for this query:

```
Syntax error on line 12 at column 4 of file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xq near {...ml")/text/$liv return $val ...} 
  XPST0003: The main module must contain a query expression after any declarations in the prolog
Syntax error on line 12 at column 4 of file:/Users/mike/Desktop/temp/test.xq near {...ml")/text/$liv return $val ...} 
  XPST0003: Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
Static error(s) in query
```

I can't say I'm entirely happy with that: the second message is redundant, and the reference to a "path expression" rather odd; also some users might not know that `<eof>` means "end of file" or that lexers often treat end-of-file as a pseudo-token; but the first message is spot-on and would have avoided the need for you to post here for an explanation.